# How to improve workflow for creating a Lua-based Wireshark dissector

Tags: workflow, lua, restart, wireshark, read-eval-print-loop

I've finally created a [Dissector](http://wiki.wireshark.org/Lua/Dissectors) for my UDP protocol in [Lua for Wireshark](http://wiki.wireshark.org/Lua), but the work flow is just horrendous. It consists of editing my custom Lua file in my editor, then double-clicking my example capture file to launch Wireshark to see the changes. If there was an error, Wireshark informs me via dialogs or a red line in the Tree analysis sub-pane. I then re-edit my custom Lua file and then close that Wireshark instance, then double-click my example capture file again. It's like compiling a C file and only seeing one compiler error at a time.

Is there a better (faster) way of looking at my changes, without having to restart Wireshark all the time?

At the time, I was using Wireshark 1.2.9 for Windows with Lua enabled.

Comment: Are there any useful lua dissector tutorials and class documentation?

Comment: @harper Classes and functions are documented at https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/wsluarm_modules.html

Comment: @Lekensteyn Yes, there is a list of classes and functions. But it was asked for a workflow instead of that list.

Comment: @harper There is a very simple example in the [previous chapter](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/wslua_dissector_example.html), [the wiki](https://wiki.wireshark.org/Lua/Dissectors) and also a [SharkFest presentation](https://sharkfest.wireshark.org/sf15.html) on Lua dissectors by Hadriel (Tuesday session 11).

Comment: @Lekensteyn You missed it again, sorry. There is no request for an (even simple) example. It's a request for for workflow improvement.

Comment: @harper The original question was answered below, I posted the links for future readers. Reload Lua plugins should be the way to go if its bugs are fixed.

Comment: @Lekensteyn So if you want to address future readers why do you write @harper?

Answer (score 6):

The best way to automate this is by using command line. Yep, use tshark instead of loading gui thingy.

If your lua script is called "proto.lua" and it defines an protocol called "MyProto" that uses port 8888, you can test your dissector using:

```
tshark -X lua_script:proto.lua -O MyProto -V -f "port 8888"
```

- -V option makes tshark print all the info of all protocols.
- -O option filters the -V option to make it show all the info only on the listed(CSV) protocols.
- -f option filters all packets that doesn't conform to the rule. In this case any packet that is not from the right port.

Answer (score 2):

The latest Wireshark release comes with a primitive console for running lua script.  It can be found under Tools -> Lua -> Evaluate.  From there, you should be able to reload your dissector by running `dofile()`.  You'll also have to remove the previous version of your dissector.

Here's an example for a TCP-based dissector.

```
local tcp_dissector_table = DissectorTable.get("tcp.port")
tcp_dissector_table:remove(pattern, yourdissector)
yourdissector = nil

dofile("c:/path/to/dissector.lua")
```

I recommend placing this code in a function inside your file.

Now there's a problem with this answer:  **If your script created a Proto object, it seems that you can't create it again with the same id**.  The constructor for the Proto class calls the C function `proto_register_protocol()` (see `epan/wslua/wslua_proto.c`).  I can't find any lua function that will unregister the protocol.  In fact, I can't even find a C function to unregister it.

Comment: "In fact, I can't even find a C function to unregister it."  There isn't one - without Lua, there's no mechanism for registering dissectors (or other plugins) at any time other than startup time, so there was no need for *un*registering.  With Lua, it might make sense to add that (and add some IDE capabilities to Wireshark for Lua - I think somebody has an IDE written in Lua that could perhaps be used for this).

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to write a trivial wrapper function that Wireshark loads, and have it just load the real file from disk (e.g. via `dofile()`).  This could probably "trick" Wireshark into always reloading your Lua code until you're more comfortable with it and can remove this hack.

Answer (score 0):

I've been facing the same problem for quite a while, so I have decided to create a tool that would help me streamline that "horrendous workflow". The tool in question is [Wirebait](https://github.com/MarkoPaul0/WireBait). It is designed to let you run your Lua dissectors as you write them without Wireshark.

It is very quick and easy to install and use. All you have to do is load the Wirebait module and add a five liner snippet on top of your dissector script. Then if you use an IDE such as ZeroBrane Studio, Wirebait allows you to literally write and debug your code on the fly, no need for wireshark. If you don't even have a pcap file, you can use a hexadecimal string representing the data you want to dissect.